# redux createStore не работает

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Не могу создать `store`, выдает ошибку *(см. скриншоты)*.

**index.js file**

```
import store from './redux/store-redux';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

let renderPage = (state) => {

   ReactDOM.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
         <App store={store}
              pageMessages={state.pageMessages}
         postsData={state.pageProfile.postsData}
         postValue={state.pageProfile.postValue}
         dispatch = {store.dispatch.bind(store)}/>
      </React.StrictMode>,
      document.getElementById('root')
   );
}
renderPage(store.getState());

store.subscribe(()=>{
    let state = store.getState();
    renderPage(state);
});
```

**store-redux file**

```
import {combineReducers, createStore} from "redux";
import messagesReducer from "../reducers/pageMessagesReducer";
import profileReducer from "../reducers/pageProfileReducer";


let reducers = combineReducers({
    pageMessages: messagesReducer,
    pageProfile:  profileReducer
});

let store = createStore(reducers);

window.store = store;

export default store;
```

[image: TypeError]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: может перед вызовом window проверять его на отсутствие undefined т.е. if typeof window !== undefined

Comment: @Данилкин window.store здесь только ради того, чтобы показать, что store не создался. От условия ничего не изменится

Answer (score 1):

Есть очень много вариантов почему такое может произойти.

1. У вас React.StrictMode описан, но нигде не описан сам импорт реакта(если он делается глобально, то проблема не в этом)
2. Может влиять расширение файла store-redux, если он js файл, то проблема не в этом
3. Может влиять левая библиотека(что маловероятно) [ссылка](https://hinty.io/devforth/fix-webpack-imported-module-is-not-a-function-for-webpack5/)

В целом ваш код рабочий [пример](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-raman-4sgum?file=/src/store-redux.js)

Вероятно проблемы в настройках webpack или импортах.

Comment: Как можно сбросить настройки webpack?(хотя я ничего не менял) И что может быть не так в импортах?

Comment: import React from 'react' отсутствует, но используется React.StrictMode